# Where can I find the source protocol IDL files?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

My understanding of adding a new protocol to wireshark is:

> 1. Write an COBRA IDL file to describe the protocol
> 2. Run idl2wrs, it generates the C code
> 3. Update build files and build the source tree

I like to learn how to write an IDL file for a protocol and I downloaded wireshark-2.6.1 source tarball, but I cannot find any meaningful IDL source file.

The protocol I am interested is RADIUS, but except couple programming files in epan/, radius_dict.c and radius_dict.l - I actually do not know what they are - I do not see RADIUS IDL file.

So the protocol's IDL files are not released in wireshark source tree? Anywhere I can find an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

- [doc/README.idl2wrs](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.idl2wrs;h=9d3e612c2fa09c499e2f0624c388f782776bc93d;hb=HEAD)
- The files in the [idl/](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=idl;h=55e8fd778843f5489f6c07239d474590617de36c;hb=HEAD) directory
- The [idl2wrs man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/idl2wrs.html)
- The [LinuxJournal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/) article that Frank Singleton wrote, titled, ["Help with Designing or Debugging CORBA Applications"](https://web.archive.org/web/20080323093648/https://www.linuxjournal.com/node/5453/print) (It's a bit dated now, but should hopefully still give you the idea.)

Comment: I see, so not all protocols use IDL, rather it seems most do not use IDL since there are just couple protocols under idl/. Thanks.